# Can't fetch results of an SQL statement in PHP

Tags: php, sql, pdo

i'm working on a search function in **PHP**, so i do want to be able to research any keyword in all database tables, but i can't fetch the result of the SQL statement which will do :

```
SELECT * FROM All_Tables
```

here's my code :

```
$getTables = $this->db->query("show tables");
$tmpString = '';

while ($table_data = $getTables->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM))
{
    $tmpString.=$table_data[0].',';
}

$ALL_DATABASE_TABLES = substr($tmpString,0,strlen($tmpString)-1); //Remove the last ,

echo " $ALL_DATABASE_TABLES "; //  Works, it shows all database tables

$query = "SELECT * FROM $ALL_DATABASE_TABLES" ; 

$stmt = $this->db->query($query) or die(print_r($this->db->errorInfo())) ;

echo "Cool1"; // Works
echo "$ALL_DATABASE_TABLES "; //Works

// This Loop doesn't work-----------------------
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) 
{
    echo "Cool2"; // Doesn't work

    echo "$row[0]" ; // Doesn't work
}
//----------------------------------------------

$stmt->closeCursor();
```

Do you have any idea about that ? Thank you guys

Comment: You can't access arrays in double quotes. `echo $row[0];` not `echo "$row[0]";`. And you definitely can't select from all tables.

Comment: So young... This made my day...

Answer (score 2):

Your code does the following:

1. Select's a full list of tables in your database.
2. Combines the full list found in #1 into a comma-separated list.
3. Uses the comma-separated list from #2 in a `SELECT *` query, thus attempting to select every record from every table in your database in a single result.

I'm surprised you actually don't receive an error or timeout/warning. The reason is is because using a comma-separated list will attempt to do a `join` between every table. From the manual:

> INNER JOIN and , (comma) are semantically equivalent in the absence of
>   a join condition: both produce a Cartesian product between the
>   specified tables (that is, each and every row in the first table is
>   joined to each and every row in the second table).

When your table-list grows to even three or four tables and you have 5 or six columns in each table with a long list of rows, your query will take *forever* to run. Now, a normal database has 10+ tables (at least) - so MySQL would either throw an error or just timeout (in my experience) - which is why I find it odd to you're not receiving one.

What exactly is your goal, besides selecting every record from every table in your database?

If you really just want to list every record in every table, you can perform a separate `SELECT *` for each table:

```
$getTables = $this->db->query("show tables");
$tables = array();

while ($table_data = $getTables->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
    $tables[] = $table_data[0];
}

foreach ($tables as $table) {
    $stmt = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM ' . $table) or die(print_r($this->db->errorInfo()));
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
        echo $row[0] . '<br />';
    }
    $stmt->closeCursor();
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) what i really wanna do is : if the user searchs a keyword it pass it through URL `index.php?method=search&q=The_Keyword` so it should be searched in every table of the database, doens't it ?

Comment: Actually his query should select the cartesian product of every row in every table, which is pretty useless and performance-destroying.

Comment: Yep. Because you don't specify how to join the tables you'll get an enormous resultset of all the possible combinations.

Comment: @Mehdi, you are going about this wrong. You need to refine what it means to your application to "search by keyword" (which I doubt means looking for matches in every single cell of your tables). You then need to make use of [fulltext indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html) or a standalone text search server like [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) or even [CloudSearch](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/)

Comment: @Mehdi When searching, you will need to define rules such as "columns x,y,z from table A and columns g,h from table B are searchable". Not "every column in every table".

Comment: @newfurniturey but how can the user know which column be selected ?

Comment: @Mehdi *Your application* knows which columns to select! All the user has to know is something like "searches the body text of blog posts and comments".

Comment: @Mehdi The user shouldn't know your database's schema. The user should have a search form and *your code* handles searching and displaying results. If I searched for `pizza`, I don't want to know that my query matches `pizza_restaurants.name`. I just want to see the results such as "Uno's", "Domino's", etc.

Comment: @FrancisAvila & newfurniturey Thank you a lot guys !!